# Books like Béla Bollobás' The Art of Mathematics: Coffee Time in Memphis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I have been looking at *The Art of Mathematics: Coffee Time in Memphis* and *The Art of Mathematics - Take Two: Tea Time in Cambridge* by Béla Bollobás, and am really enjoying these books. I like the style of the problems, the mix in difficulty and how many of the problems have an interesting story or further reading behind them. The **'tea time but also leads to advanced topics' nature of the problems** and the **focus on exercises** is essential to me. I am looking for books that are similar, both in the style and difficulty of the problems?

Some other books I know of that are similar to what I am looking for and may help people to make suggestions are;

- *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities* by John Michael Steele.
- *Putnam and Beyond* by  Răzvan Gelca & Titu Andreescu
- *Problem-Solving Through Problems* by Loren C. Larson

My background: I am an undergraduate from the UK, soon to start my second year.

Comment: Why is this question closed? It says it "needs details or clarity." What details does someone need to answer this question? If you have something specific in mind, why not ask the OP to for those specific details in the comment? Why close a perfectly good question from a new contributor?